# Is this a valid alternative to the double checked locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I would like to use singleton pattern in a multithreaded program. Double-checked locking method seems suitable for its efficiency, however this method is broken and not easy to get right.

I write the following code hoping that it works as an alternative to the double-checked locking. Is it a correct implementation of a thread-safe singleton pattern?

```
static bool created = false;
static Instance *instance = 0;

Instance *GetInstance() {
    if (!created) {
        Lock lock;    // acquire a lock, parameters are omitted for simplicity
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Instance;
        } else {
            created = true;
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The first call will create Instance. The second call will set created to true. And finally, all other calls will return a well initialized instance.

http://voofie.com/content/192/alternative-to-double-checked-locking-and-the-singleton-pattern/

Comment: Why not simply use `Instance* GetInstance() { static Instance instance; return &instance; }`

Comment: Has anyone told you yet that singletons are evil?  The complexity people end up introducing just to create one with any semblance of thread safety is only part of the problem.

Comment: Whole singleton principle is broken, not only this implementation ;)

Comment: How does it get destroyed? What does it do if it gets used after it's destroyed? Could you have a main thread which creates the object and passes it to the threads that need it? In my experience, singletons are usually unnecessary, and complicate comprehension. Just make one and pass it around.

Comment: @KennyTM: You'd have to check that your compiler initialises local statics in a thread safe way. It's required by C++11, but no compiler fully implements C++11 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this doesn't help. If the writes to `created` and `instance` are non-atomic then there is no guarantee that the values are visible to a thread that doesn't lock the mutex.

e.g. Thread 1 calls `getInstance`. `created` is `false`, and `instance` is null, so it locks the mutex and creates a new instance. Thread 1 calls `getInstance` again, and this time sets `created` to `true`. Thread 2 now calls `getInstance`. By the vagaries of the processor's memory management it sees `created` as `true`, but there is no guarantee that it also sees `instance` as non-null, and even if it does there is no guarantee that the memory values for the pointed-to instance are consistent.

If you're not using atomics then you need to use mutexes, and must use them for all accesses to a protected variable.

Additional info: If you are using mutexes, then the compiler and runtime work together to ensure that when one thread releases a mutex lock and another thread acquires a lock on that same mutex then the second thread can see all the writes done by the first. This is not true for non-atomic accesses, and may or may not be true for atomic accesses, depending on what memory ordering constraints the compiler and runtime guarantee for you (with C++11 atomics you can choose the ordering constraints).

Comment: Updated answer with additional info.

Comment: I did use a lock (Lock lock;). Isn't it the same?

Comment: This is only the same if **all threads** use the lock, which is precisely what you are trying to avoid!

Comment: I just thought if a thread releases a lock, all the memory changes it made will be visible to all other threads. Is there any reference about what mutexes will do on the thread's cache? When I read about mutexes, I can't really find information about how thread's memory is flushed to the shared memory, and the visibility of the changes as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mutexes only guarantee that the changes made are visible to threads that subsequently acquire the the same mutex. As for how: that is a matter for the CPU. The mutex will typically use some form of memory barrier instruction, but the precise form and consequences of that will vary from CPU to CPU. There is a chapter in my book (C++ Concurrency in Action --- http://www.stdthread.co.uk/book) about the C++11 memory model and ordering guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

It has the same reliability of the double-checked locking.
You can get more with "triple check", or even "quadruple-check", but full reliability can be demonstrated to be impossible.

Please note that declaring a local-static variable will make the compiler to implement itself your same logic.

```
#include<memory>
#include "Instance.h" //or whatever...

Instance* GetInstance()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Instance> p(new Instance);
    return p.get();
}
```

If the compiler is configured for multithreading environment, it sould protect the static p with a mutex and manage the lock when initializing p at the very first call. It also should chain p destruction to the tail of the "at_exit" chain, so that -at program end- proper destruction will be performed.

[EDIT]
Since this is a requirement for C++11 and is implemented only in some C++03 pre-standard, check the compiler implementation and settings.

Right now, I can only ensure MinGW 4.6 on and VS2010 already did it.

Comment: While this is required of C++11 compilers, not all current compilers provide the necessary synchronization for local `static` objects in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: It isn't double checked if you look carefully. It is double-lock, in which different threads must be locked at least twice which ensure ordering in assignment of created and instance. Just stating it is not correct isn't helpful. Is there any situation that you think is invalid?

Comment: @Ross: behind this kind of problem there is always a conceptual limit that is described as "the two General problem". (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem for an brief description)
There is no solution. Double check, double lock, double commit etc. etc. are all approximations.

Note that -although wikipedia describes it as a "networking problem"- it can similarly formulated -by changing the subjects appropriatly- in whatever "network of lock" set of "actors" (the thread, in this case) can act.

Comment: @Ross: "Is there any situation that you think is invalid?" - three threads. The first one creates the object. The second one sets the flag. The third one sees the change to the flag and so never takes the lock. As a result it reads the instance without taking the lock, and due to some quirk of incoherent caching, doesn't see the change to the instance even though, in your opinion as an omniscient observer, the change to the instance "occurred before" the change to the flag. In fact from the POV of thread 3, it did not occur before it. So thread 3 returns a null pointer from the function.

Comment: Or equally thread 3 might "see" the change to `instance`, and so return the address of the object, but due to some quirk of incoherent caching and the fact that it hasn't taken any lock, it might not "see" the changes made to that memory in order to initialize the object. So it might return a pointer to an object that, *in thread 3*, is not initialized. For simplicity you can assume as a rule of thumb that if you don't synchronize, then the order of writes made by other threads is not guaranteed.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. What I imagine to be happening is this: Thread 1 acquire a lock, creates the object and release the lock. Cache of Thread 1 should be flushed to the share memory when the lock is released. Then thread 2 acquire a lock and set the flag. Other threads may see the flag set, even if lock of thread 2 not released. But it is ok, as the changes made by thread 1 (the variable instance and the object memory) are flushed to the share memory and visible to all other threads, so any other threads see a consistent state of the shared memory and can return a valid instance.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There's absolutely no difference between your code and double 
checked locking.  The *correct* implementation is:

```
static std::mutex m;

Singleton&
Singleton::instance()
{
    static Singleton* theOneAndOnly;
    std::lock_guard l(m);
    if (theOneAndOnly == NULL)
        theOneAndOnly = new Singleton;
    return *theOneAndOnly;
}
```

It's hard to imagine a case where this would cause a problem, and it is
guaranteed.  You do aquire the lock each time, but aquiring an
uncontested mutex should be fairly cheap, you're not accessing
Singleton's that much, and if you do end up having to access it in the
middle of a tight loop, there's nothing to stop you from acquiring a
reference to it before entering the loop, and using it.

Answer (score 1):

This code contains a race-condition, in that `created` can be read while it is concurrently being written to by a different thread.

As a result, it has undefined behaviour, and is not a valid way of writing that code.

As KennyTM pointed out in the comments, a far better alternative is:

```
Instance* GetInstance() { static Instance instance; return &instance; }
```

Comment: Since instance is an expensive object, and it may not be used. So lazy initialization is needed.

Comment: @Ross: this is lazy initialization -- function-scope statics are initialized the first time program execution "crosses" their definition. This code hands your problem over to the implementation to solve, which is great if your implementation already implements thread-safe local statics. Not so great if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

your solution will work fine, but it does one more check.

the right double check locking looks like,

```
static Instance *instance = 0; 

Instance *GetInstance() { 
    if (instance == NULL)  //first check.
    {
        Lock lock; //scope lock.
        if (instance == NULL) //second check, the second check must under the lock.
           instance = new Instance;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

the double check locking will have a good performance for it does not acquire the lock every time. and it is thread-safe the locking will gurentee there is only one instance created.

Comment: Please read http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf to see why it is broken.